# String tokenizer.nextToken() return value

Tags: java, if-statement, stringtokenizer

When using an if statement, for instance,

```
if((isInt(search1.nextToken()) == true) && search1.nextToken() != "x")
```

would the result returned by `search1.nextToken()` have different values? This is all wrapped in a while loop as well, and I'm trying to figure out what would happen.

Comment: Of course it would, you're calling `nextToken`. But this would also be trivial to verify.

Comment: One note on style- never say `if(something == true)`. Just say `if(something)`.

Comment: @Brian Gordon why not? wouldnt you understand what I'm saying more easier?

Comment: @user3051642 It's just long-held convention.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would have different values. Whenever you do nextToken it would read the next available token. I would suggest to try with a simple java program to understand better.

Comment: Hmm so for this code im testing to see if the next token is an int.. if i call the search1.nextToken inside of the if statement would it be the original token which is an int

Comment: From your code I see that there are two conditions, and each search1.nextToken() expression would get different tokens.